# Please provide me steps to bring up serial console in Ubuntu 22 (UEFI Interactive shell)

Tags: 22.04

Please provide me steps to bring up Serial console in Ubuntu 22

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto

I'm following the steps in above link, but it is not supported for the recent version